# Expo in-app-purchases: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: connectAsync

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, in-app-purchase, expo

I'm trying to follow along with expo's [in app purchases documentation.](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/in-app-purchases/). I have the android developer account and set up my in-app-purchase on that account for the same app. I'm just trying to get started with the documentation and receive an error immediately.

If you look at the documentation, I'm just trying to enter in what's in the first example. I call this function at the beginning of the render method of my app.

```
import * as InAppPurchases from 'expo-in-app-purchases';
...

const getHistory = async function(){ 
  const history = await connectAsync();
    if (history.responseCode === IAPResponseCode.OK) {
      history.results.forEach(result => {
        console.log(result)
      });
    }
}
```

And I receive these errors

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: connectAsync]
* App.js:57:19 in getHistory
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:30 in invoke
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:135:28 in invoke
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:170:17 in Promise$argument_0
- node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:45:7 in tryCallTwo

...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import in-app purchases module first. Like this:

```
import * as InAppPurchases from 'expo-in-app-purchases';

const getHistory = async function(){ 
  const history = await InAppPurchases.connectAsync();
    if (history.responseCode === IAPResponseCode.OK) {
      history.results.forEach(result => {
        console.log(result)
      });
    }
}
```

Also, note this from the documentation you linked:

> You must ensure that you have installed and configured the react-native-unimodules package before continuing.

and this:

> Note that in-app purchases require physical devices to work on both platforms and therefore cannot be tested on simulators.

Comment: Sorry, that's in my code, I just didn't include that part in my example

Comment: Please share that part as well.

Comment: So, you're still not referring `connectAsync` from `InAppPurchases` you imported. Try my code.

Comment: Either use my code, or import it like this: `import { connectAsync } from 'expo-in-app-purchases';`. But I recommend using my code because you'll probably want to use other methods from the module as well.

Comment: I get a different error with that `[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ExpoInAppPurchases.default.connectAsync')]`

Comment: Could be because of two things that I added to my answer.

Comment: I have `react-native-unimodules` installed and was testing on a physical device. Could it be because the module is only available in the bare workflow? I don't really know what that is but the docs says that `easy configuration with app.json are not yet supported.` I don't really know the significance of that either but it's the only thing I can see in the documentation that could possibly be causing this.

Comment: Yes, this is only possible with the bare workflow on Expo. I'm able to get it connecting with the examples.

Answer (score 0):

Since you used:

```
import * as InAppPurchases from 'expo-in-app-purchases';
```

That means your code should look like:
...

```
const getHistory = async function(){ 
  const history = await InAppPurchases.connectAsync();
    if (history.responseCode === InAppPurchases.IAPResponseCode.OK) {
      history.results.forEach(result => {
        console.log(result)
      });
    }
}
```